# how to add bodyType serverless.yml for post request [serverless-auto-swagger]

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, aws-serverless

Hi mates this is regarding the serverless-auto-swagger library, in serverless.ts we can add bodyType but for yml how to define the request body type? I tried adding a schema as well but it seems not getting.

> functions.yml

```
createSurvey:
  handler: src/functions/survey/createSurveyFunction.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /survey
        method: post
        cors: true
        authorizer:
          name: authorizer
          arn: ${self:custom.userPoolArn}
```

> Survey Interface

`export interface PostISurvey {    surveyTitle?: string;    surveyDesc?: string;    expireDate?: string;    questions?: any[]; }`

> serverless.yml configs

```
 autoswagger:
    title: "Survey API Documentation"
    apiType: "http"
    generateSwaggerOnDeploy: true
    typefiles: ["./src/types/surevy.d.ts"]
    schemes: ["http"]
    basePath: "/${opt:stage}"
    apiKeyHeaders: ["authorizer"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the bodyType to the http event  (see [doc](https://github.com/completecoding/serverless-auto-swagger#post-request-expected-body))

With your exemple it should be:

> function.yml

```
createSurvey:
  handler: src/functions/survey/createSurveyFunction.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /survey
        method: post
        cors: true
        bodyType: PostISurvey
        authorizer:
          name: authorizer
          arn: ${self:custom.userPoolArn}
```